# Fetching stored values for use in function logic

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, remix

Are there any benefits from fetching stored data into other functions by calling a function to call a private variable, instead of calling the private variable directly? What is best practices?

example

```
 contract PlayerExample {

    uint private maximumPlayers

    uint private players;

    function playersCount() public view returns (uint) {
        return players;
    }

    function playerSlotsLeft() public view returns (uint) {
        return (maximumPlayers - players);
        //or is it better to do 
        //return (maximumPlayers - playersCount());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a gas perspective - specifically, if this were ever being called by another contract as part of a transaction, rather than just a call being made directly - then not having another function call on the stack is going to be cheaper:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1; 

contract PlayerExample {
    uint private maximumPlayers = 10;
    uint private players = 5;

    function playerSlotsLeft() public view returns (uint) {
        return (maximumPlayers - players);
    }
}
```

- Transaction cost: 21874
- Execution cost: 602

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1; 

contract PlayerExample {
    uint private maximumPlayers = 10;
    uint private players = 5;

    function playersCount() public view returns (uint) {
        return players;
    }

    function playerSlotsLeft() public view returns (uint) {
        return (maximumPlayers - playersCount());
    }
}
```

- Transaction cost: 21931
- Execution cost: 659

Comment: Do you think it's a valuable trade off to have another function call on the stack if it aids in readability of the source code?

Comment: In this case - and in cases where the function is simply acting as an internal getter for a variable - no. In my opinion all you're doing is adding a level of indirection, making it _less_ readable. Instead of just looking for the variable definition - which in an ideal world would be a) well-commented, b) have an intuitive name - you first have to look for the function, realise that it's just returning the variable, and _then_ look for the variable. And it (potentially) costs more gas :-)

Comment: (Even if you're sure this code would never be called by another contract as part of a transaction, and only ever be called as part of a "call", you have to remember that a larger contract costs more to deploy in the first place. Maybe one such function wouldn't make much different, but if you end up writing a function for each variable then costs are going to increase accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a function you have the possibility to add extra functionality to it when needed, for example access checks. Otherwise I don't see much benefits in using a function.